# Replacing Image with that of a bigger size (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm doing image stitching on a video and this is basically how my loop works:
frame1 + frame2 = stitched
replace frame1 as stitched and repeat loop.

I tried resizing frame1 to the size of stitched and then using stitched.copyTo(frame1) but that doesn't seem to work. :(

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if stitched is larger than frame1, it won't work. please show the relevant piece of code (includung the allocations)

Comment: resize(frame1, frame1, Size(stitched.cols, stitched.rows), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
stitched.copyTo(frame1);

Yes, stitched will be bigger then frame1. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: since you seem to overwrite frame1 anyway, why the expensive resize ? can't you just replace frame1 with stitched ? i don't even see, where you need the copy.

Comment: Take a look at my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440894/issues-with-sticthing-together-two-images/25460497#25460497 I used OpenCV's Stitcher class.

Comment: "but that doesn't seem to work. :(" what exactly does not work? Copying or stitching to copied? Does it work if you save the result to file and load stitched + third image?

Comment: "frame1+frame2=stitched". Is this stitched image displayed correctly? It seems that you are focusing on the steps after the stitching to fix the bug, and there is no mention on whether the stiched image is being displayed as expected for the first iteration.

Comment: "frame1+frame2=stitched". Is this stitched image displayed correctly?

Yes the stitched stitches and displays just fine. No issues with this part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Free data allocated for frame1
frame1.release();

// Clone stiched image
frame1 = stiched.clone();
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. My frame1 is still showing the previous image. It's strange.

I put print statements before and after these lines to make sure it reaches there and it does but...nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

I have not been working with OpenCV in a long time, but here's my sugesstion

Assuming you stitched the two images sucessfully, the MAT stiched should be the resulting image. So, instead of copying stitched to frame1, `stitched.copyTo(frame1)`, why not just `imshow(stitched)` ?

Give us what you have done so far, so we can understand your question better :D